# Java SocketChannel write blocked while reading

Tags: java, sockets, socketchannel

I am trying to use `SocketChannel.write` and `SocketChannel.read` at the same time in two different threads (Android API Level 25).

I configured the SocketChannel as **blocking mode**.

For reading, I created an endless loop to read everything from server:

```
// Make socketChannel.read() return after 500ms at most
socketChannel.socket().setSoTimeout(500);
while(!SHUTDOWN) {
    int read = socketChannel.read(buffer);
    if(read > 0 ){
      // Do something nice
      break;
    }
}
```

And for writing, I write data each 10 seconds.

The problem is, I found that sometimes the writing operations were blocked while reading.

But if I make the reading thread sleep for a short period in each loop, e.g. 100ms, this problem won't appear anymore.

**looks like reading thread is blocking writing thread**

AFAIK, TCP connections can offer bi-direction operations at the same time. Can anyone help to explain this?

Comment: You are completely ignoring the information returned by the `read()` method. Don't do that.

Comment: Sorry, @EJP, This is just a demo to show I am reading data in a loop, fixed it

Comment: It will be nice if the guy who downvote this question can explain why

Comment: It will be nice if you explain what 'just a demo' has to do with perpetrating a basic programming error. Also what exactly is the point of sleeping the read thread.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: @fileyfood500 unfortunately I didn't find a reasonable explanation for this problem, if you have any further information, I would love to know.

Comment: @MrROY I found that for a TCP connection, the socket reader/writer does use a lock so that reads and writes don't happen at the same time. From what I read, the normal pattern for a TCP client is to connect (3 way handshake between client and server), write a message (with packets, acks, etc), wait for a response, and then disconnect. The protocol doesn't isn't meant for the client to read and write at the same time. Some usecases have a back and forth (client writes, then reads, then writes, then reads, then writes, etc), but no continuous read. In this case UDP might be an option?

Comment: I too is facing the same issue, while reading a continuous stream of data. It is working fine for initial 10-15 mins appx and suddenly blocks itself. I too thought of delaying for 10 sec. I landed up here . I too wanted to know why it is like that for TCP connection.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [TCP Wikipedia - Flow Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Flow_control):

> TCP uses an end-to-end flow control protocol to avoid having the
>   sender send data too fast for the TCP receiver to receive and process
>   it reliably. Having a mechanism for flow control is essential in an
>   environment where machines of diverse network speeds communicate. For
>   example, if a PC sends data to a smartphone that is slowly processing
>   received data, the smartphone must regulate the data flow so as not to
>   be overwhelmed.

Comment: Thanks, But this doesn't explain why the reading blocks the writing

Comment: The reader blocks the writer when the reader read too slowly.

Comment: How do I know if the reader is reading too slowly? I am initializing a reader on startup, and getting immediately blocked on writing (because there is nothing to read at this time).

Comment: I reviewed the flow control wiki section (which I had actually read before I found this post), but it suggests that the reader from a server blocks the writer from a client, or vice-versa. It looks to me like the question is about why a client's reader (on a separate thread) is blocking the client's writer from sending messages to the server. The client is blocking itself locally, but sockets are non-blocking. I have the same question.

Comment: Please post your code in a new question because I suspect you're confusing reader/writer vs client/server. Code is unambiguous.

Comment: @Aubin, I believe the asker is using a TCP client to read continuously and write every 10 seconds. Am I wrong about this?